# how do I get this effect?

Tags: html

http://www.apple.com/why-mac/
has a cool little thing where you hover your cursor over the image and it scrolls upward to show hidden text. 

I'm wanting to create a mockup with that same effect, where I have the mockup as one flat background image and then place the scrolling images on top of it.
Any ideas as to how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with jQuery scrollable: http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the source for the page (with Firefox/Firebug, by the way, which is awesome for this kind of reverse-engineering) I see that the javascript framework Scriptaculous is in use.  Specifically, the [BlindUp](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/effect-blindup) animation appears to be the one in use on that page.

Comment: I used Firefox's FireBug for this, but I had the phone ringing, etc., so you beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apple uses [Scritaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) for that effect.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Transitions?](http://webkit.org/blog/138/css-animation/)

(From the link above):

> Transitions are specified using the following properties:
>
> transition-property – What property should animate, e.g., opacity.
>   transition-duration – How long the transition should last.
>   transition-timing-function – The timing function for the transition
>   (e.g., linear vs. ease-in vs. a custom cubic bezier function).
>   transition – A shorthand for all three properties.
>
> Here is a simple example:

```
div {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

div:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```